# how to use multiple header and footer in php site?

Tags: php, templates, header, footer

I have a PHP website, and I want to use several header and footer for this script templates. So how can I do this?

At the moment my index.php is called header.php and footer.php, and I want to use this only for the home page and the other page is to call the header-one.php and the footer-one.php (example). Can I do this?

Example my index.php code.

```
<?php
$view->title = $LANG["HOMEPAGE_TITLE"];

$view->description = $LANG["HOMEPAGE_DESCRIPTION"];

$view->keywords = $LANG["HOMEPAGE_TAGS"];

$view->header = $view->render(DIR_TEMPLATE.WEBSITE_TEMPLATE.'/header.php');

$view->footer = $view->render(DIR_TEMPLATE.WEBSITE_TEMPLATE.'/footer.php');

echo $view->render(DIR_TEMPLATE.WEBSITE_TEMPLATE.'/index.php');
?>
```

Comment: Can you give example? For use it?

Answer (score 1):

You can put condition on rendering template. I've shown you example if `$user` is admin then render `header_admin.php` and `footer_admin.php` if not then load `header.php` `footer.php`.

```
if($user === 'admin')
    $view->header = $view->render(DIR_TEMPLATE.WEBSITE_TEMPLATE.'/header_admin.php');
else
    $view->header = $view->render(DIR_TEMPLATE.WEBSITE_TEMPLATE.'/header.php');

if($user === 'admin')
    $view->footer = $view->render(DIR_TEMPLATE.WEBSITE_TEMPLATE.'/footer_admin.php');
else
    $view->footer = $view->render(DIR_TEMPLATE.WEBSITE_TEMPLATE.'/footer.php');
```

Comment: hi thanks! Important thing is not in this matter. So I need it. For example, when calling the index.php (home page template) only to header.php, footer.php and other pages need to call other header and footer page. I have several pages (login, dashboard, register, settings, etc.), And for this page x need  a cell to the header-one and footer-one page.

Comment: @oktamyoqubov
approx how many different headers and footers you've ?
depending this I can suggest you most suitable option..